# Edit file based on jar property using ant

Tags: java, xml, ant, properties

I am VERY new to using ant. I want to build a jar and edit a file only if my `flag` condition is 1

Right now I have some code:

```
<target name = "create_jar">
    <script language="javascript">
    ...
        create_jar.setProperty("flag", flag);//where flag is some boolean value
    </script>

    //if "${flag}" = 1
       //then:
        <replaceregexp ...></replaceregexp>

    //else continue as usual
    ...
```

If any one could help me make out what should be in my `if flag = 1` statements it would be much appreciated.

Just to be concise, my `replaceregexp` works and my `script` works to get me the right value

**EDIT** running apache ant version 1.9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some more searching it appears I want to use:

```
<project name="create_jar" xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
...
...
    <replace... if:true="${flag}">
    <replace... unless:true="${flag}">
...
```

when using ant > 1.9.1

Comment: this is a better answer than mine, i will delete my answer as ant-contrib has not been updated since 2008